# Creating and populating monthly columns from rows of data

Tags: r, csv, time, rows

I have a CSV file with multiple rows of data for each person. Each row corresponds to a month. They are described by the variables 'year' (e.g. 2019) and 'month' (which goes from 1-12). On each row are monthly expenses in different categories (e.g. 'clothing').

My goal is to look at expenses in a certain category ('clothing'), over all the years ('year', 2018-2020) months ('month', 1-12) for each person ('aid').

Is it a good idea to try to get everything for each person on one row?

I think I have the start of that here for the id variable 'aid' and then I think I need to create and populate variables for clothing per month (something like 'clothing-2019-oct'):

```
people.df<-as.data.frame(infile.df$aid)  
names(people.df)<-"aid"  
people.df<-unique(people.df)
```

How would I get 'clothing-2019-oct', 'clothing-2019-nov' etc.

This should hopefully give an idea of what my dataset looks like:

```
> dput(infile.df)
structure(list(date = c("2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", 
"2019-11-01", "2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", "2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", 
"2020-02-01", "2016-11-01", "2016-12-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-02-01"
), year = c(2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L), month = c(12L, 1L, 
2L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L), aid = c("1hg6d", 
"1hg6d", "1hg6d", "7gjfgg", "7gjfgg", "7gjfgg", "8hdf9", "8hdf9", 
"8hdf9", "hf43dy", "hf43dy", "hf43dy", "hf43dy"), clothing = c("98.4911", 
"98.4911", "98.4911", "1125.61", "1125.61", "1125.61", "1584.65", 
"0", "390.4", "4327.7", "2446.5", "2489", "0"), culture = c("54.1325", 
"54.1325", "54.1325", "618.657", "618.657", "618.657", "2494.5", 
"28.5", "0", "4859.31", "1115", "0", "1940")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data?

Comment: Hi @MariaThorson. Whether it is a good idea to convert your data from long to wide depends on the type of analysis you are trying to perform. But from the description of your dataset I would say, that I don't see any reason to convert the data to wide format as it is already in so-called tidy format. Otherwise I would recommend to have a look at tidyr::pivot_wider or search for how to convert or reshape from long to wide. There are several questions on this issue.

Comment: You should share a reproducble example using `dput` and also show expected output for the same. Read how to give a reproducible example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269.

Comment: @RonakShah I tried adding a reproducible example in the original post. Is it clearer?

Comment: @stefan Thanks! Trying to figure out which route to take. Reading up on tidy format now. I'm just so used to having each row be an individual that tidy format will take some getting used to :)

Comment: Firstly, I think you have read your data incorrectly. Everything is in 1 column. Try reading it with `infile.df <- read.csv2('filename.csv')` (Notice the 2 in `read.csv2`)

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks! That looks more readable. I've updated the original post again.

Comment: What would be your expected output for this data?